# Android how to set 2 TextView side by side programmatically?

Tags: java, android, textview

How i can display two textview side by side in Java ? 
I succeeded to do  in xml !

My code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a `LinearLayout` in my `activity_layout`.

```
    LinearLayout lm=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linearlayout1);
```

Make `LinearLayout` of type horizontal, dynamically.

```
     LinearLayout llh=new LinearLayout(context);
     llm.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Then created two `TextView` dynamically

```
     TextView tv1=new TextView(context);
     TextView tv2=new TextView(context);
```

finally add these two `TextView`'s to the horizontal `LinearLayout` (that we created dynamically) and later the same layout to the xml layout.

```
llh.addView(tv1);
llh.addView(tv2);
lm.addView(llh);
```

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: may i know what have you tried so that i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Java Code,

```
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLay);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(ActivityName.this);
    tv1.setText("TextView 1");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam1.weight = 0.5f;
    tv1.setLayoutParams(childParam1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(ActivityName.this);
    tv2.setText("TextView 2");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam1.weight = 0.5f;
    tv2.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

    layout.addView(tv1);
    layout.addView(tv2);
```

and xml code,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/mainLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution:**
use online converter 
[http://www.xmltojava.com/][1]

**Second Solution:**
inflate your layout

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layoutView = mInflater.inflate(R.rowLayout, null);
TextView tvOne=(TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I try to do

```
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_LV);


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                            (
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                            );
                    //ll.setOrientation(orientation);
                    // params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
                        LinearLayout llh=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length(); i++) 
                    {

                        final TextView txtLabel = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        final TextView txtValue = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                        jsonLabel = fields.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_LABEL) ; //+ "\n";
                        jsonValue = fields.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_VALUE) ; //+ "\n";

                        //txtLabel.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        //txtValue.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        //txtLabel.setWidth(pixels);

                        txtLabel.setLayoutParams(params);
                        txtValue.setLayoutParams(params);


                        txtValue.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                        txtLabel.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

                        //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);

                        txtLabel.setText(jsonLabel);
                        txtValue.setText(jsonValue);

                        txtLabel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        txtValue.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                        //txtLabel.


                        llh.addView(txtLabel);
                        llh.addView(txtValue);

                    }

                        ll.addView(llh);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `android:layout_weight` only after setting `android:layout_width` to `"0dp"`, try this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```